# General formulation for fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, partition-function

Let us look at a set of fermionic creation and annihilation operators $b_n$, $b_n^\dagger$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. What is the precise relationship between this and this sequence [here](http://oeis.org/A000009) (partition function)?

Comment: I was reminded of Appendix B of the below ... Have a look. https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cds.cern.ch/record/1383342/files/978-3-642-14090-7_BookBackMatter.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi8kpOh4rnKAhXE8XIKHVrMCvoQFggfMAE&usg=AFQjCNGpyUltKfekXtza6xsRu1USVA3KVg&sig2=cu656SAhDvIoiPe1w4Rb4w

Comment: Can you take advantage of (19) of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What *is* the expression for the generating function?

Comment: This question (v1) has been flagged by an anonymous user as being "a current contest problem for an ongoing French undergraduate physics competition, near verbatim after translation into English." If anyone has information of this please share it here.